# Missing Button Placed after ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a layout with 3 button at the top in a row and then a ListView followed by a button below the listView.
This is my layout.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_top10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP 10"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_top100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP 100"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_top10"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_showAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show All"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_top100"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/LV_Device"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_top10"
        android:layout_above="@id/LV_Device"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_clearResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Results"
        android:layout_below="@id/LV_Device"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will give a result like this

[image]

If i add some values to the ListView then its ok, the button below will be show

[image]

But if the listview becomes larger than the screen size then the button below that will not be visible even after scrolling to the bottom of the listView

[image]

How to solve this issue?? I don't want button to be fixed at the bottom of the screen. I want the button to be show at the end of the ListView only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `ListView`'s height to `0dip`. Then change the attribute

```
android:layout_above="@id/LV_Device"
```

to

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/btn_clearResult"
```

Finally, modify the last button by removing `android:layout_below` and add instead `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: Thanks..this works..but as i already said i dont want button to be fixed at the bottom of the screen. I want button to be seen at the end of ListView. How to do that?

Comment: Then you should switch to a LinearLayout and use weights instead. However you should know that ListView doesn't really support the "wrap_content" height. It always assumes a height of 3 rows when you set it to wrap_content. The whole point of ListView is to be able to scroll through tens of thousands (or more) of items efficiently.

Comment: hmm.ohk. as i cant find a perfect answer for what i am searching.. i think your suggestion is close to perfection.. Thanks. But i really dont think linear layout will be able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you got the answer, this is for those who still come in search of the answer for your question. You should be using `ListView.addFooterView(yourbutton)` to your list. 
(but don't forget to put this statement before setting adapter for your listview, as stated in the document.)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To help non native English speakers and maintain a useful, high quality, well written Q&A reference site please don't use 'txt spk' in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Shijilal
     you maybe try this
   
       
         your top  button
       
       
       
         your bottom group button

Comment: means..group both top and bottom button??

Answer (score 0):

put your RelativeLayout in a scroll view this way your button will be displayed even after the scroll use this might work

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dip">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_top10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP 10" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_top100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOP 100"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_top10" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_showAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show All"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_top100" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LV_Device"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_top10"
        android:layout_above="@id/LV_Device" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clearResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Results"
        android:layout_below="@id/LV_Device" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no its not working..its showing only the "Clear Result" Button

Comment: I have edited the my post check this one now if it says end tag missing then add closing </Scrollview>

Comment: now its showing all buttons. but the ListView's height is not increasing according to the number of items. Its just showing one,with a small scroll which dont even scroll :( . http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/3871/misbut2.png

Answer (score 0):

Initialy no item in the listView.so clear result button at the top. After add some item clear button goes down. But when more items are added clear button goes down & out of screen resolution. I want to know that Initialy when items are added clear button goes down. when clear button reached at bottom then it will not goes down further. you can add more items in the list view.